# Generate unique list variable

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a C# program where I have a list (`List<string>`) of unique strings. These strings represent the name of different cases. It is not important what is is. But they have to be unique.

```
cases = new List<string> { "case1", "case3", "case4" }
```

Sometimes I read some cases saved in a text format into my program. Sometime the a case stored on file have the same name as a case in my program.I have to rename this new case. Lets say that the name of the case I load from a file is case1.

But the trouble is. How to rename this without adding a large random string. In my case it should ideally be called case2, I do not find any good algorithm which can do that. I want to find the smalles number I can add which make it unique.

Comment: I have tested all the solutions and all working. It is more a matter of taste which to use:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use a `HashSet` that only accepts unique values.

```
List<string> cases = new List<string>() { "case1", "case3", "case4" };
HashSet<string> hcases = new HashSet<string>(cases);

string Result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => "case" + x).First(x => hcases.Add(x));
// Result is "case2"
```

in this sample i try to add elements between 1 and 100 to the hashset and determine the first sucessfully `Add()`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple. Get the max number of case currently stored in the list, increment by one and add the new value:

```
var max = myList.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring("case".Length))) + 1;
myList.Add("case" + max);
```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=1I6ezAnS4x).

EDIT: For filling any "holes" within your collection you may use this:

```
var tmp = myList;
var firstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(myList[0].Substring("case".Length));
for(int i = firstIndex; i < tmp.Count; i++) {
    var curIndex = Convert.ToInt32(myList[i].Substring("case".Length)); 
    if (curIndex != i) 
    {
        myList.Add("case" + (curIndex + 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

It checks for every element in your list if its number behind the case is equal to its index in the list. The loop is stopped at the very first element where the condition is broken and therefor you have a hole in the list.

Comment: i think this is a good enough starting point as it will always increment, based on the highest value in the list - plus 1

Comment: The problem with this is that it would use the next max number, not 2, which as the OP states is ideally what he wants.

Comment: actually - you are right sr28 -just grasped that strange nuance

Comment: @sr28 Now it should also fill the holes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of unique strings consider to use a `HashSet<string>` instead. Since you want incrementing numbers that sounds as if you actually should use a custom class instead of a `string`. One that contains a name and a number property. Then you can increment the number and if you want the full name (or override `ToString`) use `Name + Number`.

Lets say that class is `Case` you could fill a `HashSet<Case>`. [`HashSet.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `false` on duplicates. Then use a loop which increments the number until it could be added.

Something like this:

```
var cases = new HashSet<Case>();
// fill it ...

// later you want to add one from file:
while(!cases.Add(caseFromFile))
{
    // you will get here if the set already contained one with this name+number
    caseFromFile.Number++;
}
```

A possible implementation:

```
public class Case 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + Number;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Case other = obj as Case;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return other.ToString() == this.ToString();
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (ToString() ?? "").GetHashCode();
    }
    // other methods
}
```